# Windows tool to display MAC addresses for nearby access points?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

My Firefox sends MAC addresses of nearby access points when a geolocation javascript function is called.

Is there a Windows tool which can display the same information?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `netsh` to get a listing of nearby access points:

```
netsh wlan show network mode=bssid
```

Answer (score 1):

[inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/).